# Uncaught TypeError: cannot create property '35' on string ''

Tags: javascript, html, artificial-intelligence, minimax, connect-four

I am currently in the process of making a Connect Four AI using the minimax algorithm. I have made the board and win/draw checks, and have finished implementing the AI. However, when I go to test it, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '35' on string ''
    at Board.insert (board.js:394:26)
    at player.js:29:15
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Player.getBestMove (player.js:27:33)
    at script.js:8:20
```

I have looked through every similar question I could find, and Google has not been of any more help. I am basing most of these functions off of [this Tic-Tac-Toe AI tutorial](https://alialaa.com/blog/tic-tac-toe-js), but the `getLowestEmptyCell()` method is my own.

**board.js:**

```js
export default class Board {
  constructor(state = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]) {
    this.state = state;
  }


  printFormattedBoard() {
    let formattedString = '';
    this.state.forEach((cell, index) => {
      formattedString += cell ? ` ${cell} |` : `   |`;
      if ((index + 1) % 7 === 0) {
        formattedString = formattedString.slice(0, -1);
        if (index < 41) formattedString += '\n\u2015\u2015\u2015 \u2015\u2015\u2015 \u2015\u2015\u2015 \u2015\u2015\u2015 \u2015\u2015\u2015 \u2015\u2015\u2015 \u2015\u2015\u2015\n'
      }
    });

    console.log('%c' + formattedString, 'color: #c11dd4; font-size: 16px;');
  }


  isEmpty() {
    return this.state.every(cell => !cell);
  }

  isFull() {
    return this.state.every(cell => cell);
  }

  isTerminal() {
    if (this.isEmpty()) return false;


    /* 320 lines of winning combinations */



    if (this.isFull()) {
      return { 'winner': 'draw' };
    }

    return false;
  }


  getLowestEmptyCell(index) {
    if (index > 41 || index < 0 || this.state[index]) return NaN;

    let i = 0;

    if (index >= 0) i = 35;
    if (index >= 7) i = 28;
    if (index >= 14) i = 21;
    if (index >= 21) i = 14;
    if (index >= 28) i = 7;
    if (index >= 35) i = 0;

    for (i; i > -1; i -= 7) {
      if (!this.state[index + i]) return index + i;
    }
  }


  insert(symbol, position) {
    if (![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41].includes(position)) throw new Error('Cell index does not exist or is not possible!');

    if(!['r', 'y'].includes(symbol)) throw new Error('The symbol can only be an r or a y!');

    if (this.state[position]) return false;

    position = this.getLowestEmptyCell(position);
    this.state[position] = symbol; // error thrown here
    return true;
  }


  getAvailableMoves() {
    let moves = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      if (!this.state[i]) moves.push(this.getLowestEmptyCell(i));
    }

    return moves;
  }
}
```

**player.js:**

```js
import Board from './board.js';

export default class Player {
  constructor(maxDepth =  -1) {
    this.maxDepth = maxDepth;
    this.nodesMap = new Map();
  }


  getBestMove(board, maximising = true, callback = () => {}, depth = 0) {
    if (depth === 0) this.nodesMap.clear();

    if (board.isTerminal() || depth === this.maxDepth) {
      if (board.isTerminal().winner === 'r') {
        return 100 - depth;
      } else if (board.isTerminal().winner === 'y') {
        return -100 + depth;
      }

      return 0;
    }


    if (maximising) {
      let best = -100;

      board.getAvailableMoves().forEach(index => {
        const child = new Board([...board.state]);
        child.insert('r', index);

        const nodeValue = this.getBestMove(child, false, callback, depth + 1);
        best = Math.max(best, nodeValue);

        if (depth === 0) {
          const moves = this.nodesMap.has(nodeValue) ? `${this.nodesMap.get(nodeValue)},${index}` : index;
          this.nodesMap.set(nodeValue, moves);
        }
      });


      if (depth === 0) {
        let returnValue;
        if (typeof this.nodesMap.get(best) === 'string') {
          const arr = this.nodesMap.get(best).split(',');
          returnValue = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        } else {
          returnValue = this.nodesMap.get(best);
        }

        callback(returnValue);
        return returnValue;
      }

      return best;
    }


    if (!maximising) {
      let best = 100;

      board.getAvailableMoves().forEach(index => {
        const child = new Board([...board.state]);
        child.insert('y', index);

        const nodeValue = this.getBestMove(child, false, callback, depth + 1);
        best = Math.max(best, nodeValue);

        if (depth === 0) {
          const moves = this.nodesMap.has(nodeValue) ? `${this.nodesMap.get(nodeValue)},${index}` : index;
          this.nodesMap.set(nodeValue, moves);
        }
      });


      if (depth === 0) {
        let returnValue;
        if (typeof this.nodesMap.get(best) === 'string') {
          const arr = this.nodesMap.get(best).split(',');
          returnValue = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        } else {
          returnValue = this.nodesMap.get(best);
        }

        callback(returnValue);
        return returnValue;
      }

      return best;
    }
  }
}
```

**script.js:**

```js
import Board from './classes/board.js';
import Player from './classes/player.js';

const board = new Board(["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]);
const player = new Player();
console.log(player.getBestMove(board));
board.printFormattedBoard();
//console.log(player.nodesMap);
```

I sense that this is not anything to do with the functionality itself, but rather my cluelessness and trying to implement a custom function in the wrong places.

UPDATE: After doing many console.logs (but probably not enough), I have determined that using an array to initialise a new `Board` class along with `...board.state` actually allows the `insert()` function to see that there is still, in fact, a usable `this.state` value with 42 empty strings in an array.

Comment: Please for the love of Brendan Eich and all JS that is holy use a playground for a minimal reproducible example, such as https://jsfiddle.net or https://codesandbox.io - it's *extremely* hard to debug code when we can't even run it or tinker with it ourselves; not to mention you've excluded 320 lines of code that could potentially be the cause of the bug.

Comment: @caTS If I could do that with multiple files, I would. However, with these 320 lines, they are all really just copy and paste, and only the indices are different for each one.

Comment: can you `console.log([...board.state])` in both 2 locations in player.js ?

Comment: @A.Khaled i did, it's the same for both places

Comment: Try to `console.log(this.state)` before inserting. We want to make sure state is array when you try to insert.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `Board.state` is a string (instead of the array that you may expect).

Since strings are immutable, the following assignment is illegal and may (depending on your js-engine) throw the error that you mentioned:

```js
const state: any = "x";
state[35] = 1;
```

[Playgrond Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCGUCmMC8MBEAPDBuAUAsgNoDMArALpowCMB+QA)

- click `Run` to see the expected error

To test, if this is really the case you can set a breakpoint on the line that throws and check the `state` variable or log the type `console.log(this.state, typeof this.state)`

To avoid such issues, you should check the type of the state parameter in the constructor and throw an error if it's not of the expected type (i.e. array of string) - or use typescript which will help for such simple errors (note, that the [Playgrond Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCGUCmMC8MBEAPDBuAUAsgNoDMArALpowCMB+QA) shows an error on the assignment line and shows a meaningful error when you hoover the mouse over the line: "Index signature in type 'String' only permits reading."